# Tkinter button only works once

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

Tkinter button only runs a separate script once

Hello all, Im a new to python and raspberry pi and have been searching high and low on how to get a Tkinter button to run a script more than once on my raspberry pi. From research I believe it has something to do with **name**="**main**", but I cant figure out what needs to be done and why. My button runs a separate python file (called SendRF.py) in the same directory that generates an RF signal, it works the first time but then the button click does nothing else after. Any advice would be much appreciated :)

```
from tkinter import *

#create a window
window =Tk()
window.title("Chappers Home Automation project")

#define a function
def test_function ():
    import SendRF

#create a button
B = Button(text ="Test Button 1", command=test_function)

B.pack(padx = 100, pady = 50)
window.mainloop()
```

No error messages appear. The button sends the RF signal when pressed the first time, but nothing happens for further button clicks.

Comment: This probably has more to do with you importing a module to presumably run side effects. Why not import it once at the top of the file, put all side effect code into one function in `SendRF.py`, then run `SendRF.send_signal()` inside the callback?

Comment: I think @Carcigenicate is right.  When you import a script, it is executed.  If however you try importing it again, as it has already been "imported", it doesn't do it again.  I guess import was not meant for script but for functions.

I suggest you place your script as a definition and at the end add a classic __name__ if statement as follow :

    def x():
        pass

    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        x()

That way, your function can still be executed as a script but won't be executed during import.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import a module multiple times. Each additional import for the same module is a NOP. You need to functionize whatever is in sendRF, and call that function in `test_function`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the function is working correctly by adding a simple print statement inside your function

```
from tkinter import *

#create a window
window =Tk()
window.title("Chappers Home Automation project")

#define a function
def test_function ():
    import SendRF
    print('CHECK') 

#create a button
B = Button(text ="Test Button 1", command=test_function)

B.pack(padx = 100, pady = 50)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working one time, cause you alredy have the SendRf function mported, you need to close it, after to import again